# Why do the c libraries and language define _name and then typedef or pound define _name name?

Tags: c, syntax, macros

It seems that the C libraries and language has a lot of useless type names. For example, C has a built in type `_Bool` and there is a macro in `stdbool.h`, `#define bool _Bool`. Why didn't C just have `bool` built in instead of `_Bool`? I found more examples in `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`. Like this:

```c
# define WEXITSTATUS(status)    __WEXITSTATUS (status)
# define WTERMSIG(status)   __WTERMSIG (status)
# define WSTOPSIG(status)   __WSTOPSIG (status)
# define WIFEXITED(status)  __WIFEXITED (status)
# define WIFSIGNALED(status)    __WIFSIGNALED (status)
# define WIFSTOPPED(status) __WIFSTOPPED (status)
# ifdef __WIFCONTINUED
#  define WIFCONTINUED(status)  __WIFCONTINUED (status)
# endif
```

My question is why bother declaring a function `__FUNCTIONNAME (arg)` and then `#define FUNCTIONNAME(arg) __FUNCTIONNAME(arg)`? Why not just declare `FUNCTIONNAME(arg)` to start with?

Another example in `stdio.h`:

```
extern FILE *__stdinp;
extern FILE *__stdoutp;
extern FILE *__stderrp;
```

And later:

```
#define stdin __stdinp
#define stdout __stdoutp
#define stderr __stderrp
```

Like seriously, why? What is wrong with just defining them then declaring them like this:

```
extern FILE *stdin;
extern FILE *stdout;
extern FILE *stderr;
```

Why didn't they just declare the functions without the underscores and then have no need for these macros?

Comment: The double-underscore names are implementation-specific built-in functions.

Comment: I think the `bool` stuff is for compatibility with different historical proposals.

Comment: @Barmar I have seen that name before on the site, and I agree that bracketless if statements are iffy, but what do you mean by implementaton-specific built in functions?

Comment: Names beginning with two underscores are reserved to the implementation. This is usually used for invoking operations that the compiler recognizes specially. `__TERMSIG()` might be assembly code, for instance.

Comment: Don’t forget that C dates back to the early 70s. Do your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about namespace management.

Names prefixed with two underscores or an underscore and an upper case letter are implementation-reserved. An implementation may expose them virtually indiscriminately (well, it's not really very clear which reserved names belong to compilers and which to libc implementations).

Names like `WIFCONTINUED`, on the other hand, belong to the user (and `<sys/wait.h>` under POSIX), and `stdlib.h` shouldn't contain them under POSIX.

GLIBC exposes them from `stdlib.h` only conditionally:

```
#if (defined __USE_XOPEN || defined __USE_XOPEN2K8) && !defined _SYS_WAIT_H
/* XPG requires a few symbols from <sys/wait.h> being defined.  */
# include <bits/waitflags.h>
# include <bits/waitstatus.h>

/* Define the macros <sys/wait.h> also would define this way.  */
# define WEXITSTATUS(status)    __WEXITSTATUS (status)
# define WTERMSIG(status)   __WTERMSIG (status)
# define WSTOPSIG(status)   __WSTOPSIG (status)
# define WIFEXITED(status)  __WIFEXITED (status)
# define WIFSIGNALED(status)    __WIFSIGNALED (status)
# define WIFSTOPPED(status) __WIFSTOPPED (status)
# ifdef __WIFCONTINUED
#  define WIFCONTINUED(status)  __WIFCONTINUED (status)
# endif
#endif  /* X/Open or XPG7 and <sys/wait.h> not included.  */
```

and it's not including them by `#including` `<sys/wait.h>` probably because `<sys/wait.h>` likely has other stuff that shouldn't be included even if the condition for this `#if` (triggered by the right [feature test macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) ) block is satisfied.

When they use the prefixed forms (defined in the internal `<bits/waitstatus.h>`), `<sys/wait.h>` can then reuse the same ones (identically redefined macros don't generate warnings) and everything works even when they're both `#include`d; and no header exposes more non-reserved names than required by the standards in force (the standards in use depend on the [feature test macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) with which you compile).

Gtk is just wrong. Gtk isn't a libc implementation, and so it has no business using those reserved names.

Comment: I expect that the Gtk team have made a decision "we are part of the implementation" and deliberately use names reserved for "the implementation", limiting the possibility of damage by using `_Gtk` as a prefix (so a compiler would have to consciously decide to use the same prefix for some name if it was to actually cause the Gtk team any problems).

Comment: **it's not really very clear which reserved names belong to compilers and which to libc implementations** As far as the C standard is concerned, I don't think there's much distinction. Anything that isn't part of the user's code or third-party libraries is "the implementation".

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately. Practically, there should be a distinction, though, as libcs and compilers are usually provided by different vendors. The lack of this distinction isn't just a theoretical annoyance either. I believe there's been at least one case where two common libc and compiler implementations (glibc and clang?) clashed and one had to rename one of its reserved identifiers because of it.

Comment: As far as the programmer using them is concerned, there's no distinction. To do what you want, the standard would need multiple levels of namespacing, for the compiler, standard library, and end programmer. And they might also want another level for "popular" libraries like the POSIX API and Gtk. Where does this end?